# How to connect to webserver in NAT port forwarded virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding

I have a simple node js web server that is listening for tcp on port 1058 and udp on 1059 which is in a ubuntu virtual machine. Everything works great with a bridged connection, but I need it to be a NAT connection to monitor the network traffic from wireshark. Bridged connections bypass the OS and can not be seen in wireshark.

I've forwarded the ports, changed it to NAT, and it's not working. Below are some images of my situation.

this shows my connection working locally in the guest machine. this is good. server works..
[image]

this shows it not working from the host machine. It is unreachable even if i use other things besides postman. I also can't ping the guest machine from the host.
[image]

these are my vm network settings
[image]

[image]

and if you want more, here's a snap of packets attempting to reach it from wireshark. The one in the middle is a ping from my windows host. and you see 2 source ip's because i have another device constantly sending udp messages to it as well.
[image]

I need some advice on what else I can troubleshoot. also, i have tried turning off my firewall. it did not work.

Comment: solved, seems you need to specify localhost instead of the guest ip. to access it i needed to do localhost:1058/testing?user=username

Comment: I'm just going to end up running the tests that i want to run from another laptop. I can access the server but those messages still seem to be bypassing the OS layer and going straight to the hardware layer as they do not show on wireshark. It looks like the only way to do it is with a loopback capture? https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. It works for what asked about by using the url

http://localhost:1058/testing?username=moose

instead of

http://10.0.2.15:1058/testing?username=moose